# Add text ellipsis in case of overlapping with buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have in HTML:

```
<ng-container ...>
    <li class="list-group-item-action ...">
      <span>My long long text</span>
      <div class="buttons">
          <some ng actions here...>
      </div>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is when I shrink page borders, these buttons don't overlap my text, but rather go on a new line and the whole selection bloats a bit in its size.

So basically, on the first step I have something like that:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| My long long text    [_button1_][_button2_] |
-----------------------------------------------
```

When I shrink the page, I see this:

```
                        <------
-------------------------------------
| My long long text                 |
|            [_button1_][_button2_] |
-------------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is if I change page borders, these buttons would overlap the text and I'd see text ellipsis effect (`...`)

```
                       <------
-------------------------------------
| My long... [_button1_][_button2_] |
-------------------------------------
```

How to make it via divs/CSS?

P.S.: I'm sorry for such a weird problem description, I'm not good at UI.

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproductive sample ?

Comment: I provided some computer drawing by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` prevents the element to overflow the content outside and `text-overflow: ellipsis` places ellipsis after the text got cut. Also use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from starting a new line.

It might be easier to use a table for this because a table can force the elements into one single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like :

```
li span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: calc( 100% - 40px );
}
```

Sample :

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px auto;
  max-width: 550px;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc( 100% - 70px );
  display: inline-block;
}
li .buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>✖</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>✖</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>✖</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>✖</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conterure</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>✖</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: PS: this is a *minimal* **reproductive**

Comment: It's good, thanks a lot! Can we avoid max width/width calculations? Just make it 100% always and work from there

Comment: Yes, it's only for the example.